# Compile Source on Network Drive onto Local Drive

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I want to avoid using a service such as Dropbox to store code, even though it is convenient.  I'd prefer to store my source on a shared network drive for security reasons, and then access it from two different places.

However, when I do this using an IDE such as Netbeans, the network latency is pretty bad, even when I am on-site, not at home.

Is there a way to store source code on a network drive, but have the compiled objects (classes and war files) written to a local drive?  That way I could deploy the local war without having to write it back to a project on a network drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are describing, sounds like you really should be using [Source Control](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?W190) of some sort instead of just sharing over the network. Using source control will really make it simpler when you have multiple boxes editing the same code. Seems like the you already have network access between the boxes, so you would just need to setup your favorite Source Control repository that is supported by NetBeans, such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/).

Setting up a repo can be a pain, so a web service is always an option. I believe [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) from Atlassian allows free private repositories. There is also [Github](https://github.com/), but only public repos are free. If you need Subversion, there is [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/), but you have to pay for the service. These are the ones I am familar with, there are a bunch more Source Control services out there.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, it is possible to [mount a shared network folder](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) anywhere in the filesystem. You can mount it as source folder and have all source files there, and keep all other folders local. Your NAS box most likely supports NFS.

If you do not want to move the current mount point or if the source folder is not at its root, it is also possible to create a symbolic link to it (`ln -s target_folder link_folder`). It behaves like a pointer.